# WSO2 ESB Analytics - Production Database Configuration

Tags: wso2-das, wso2-esb

What is the best configuration for ESB Analytics database. The data grows with time and what is the best way to handle it in a production environment. Any idea on this would be really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In production you can run purging jobs [1] for old data in tables which consist of SECOND, MINUTE or even HOURLY tables as same information is aggregated into DAILY, MONTHLY, YEARLY tables.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Purging+Analytics+Data